# Should I use objects or function pointers?

Tags: oop, ada

I have a series of functions that need to be implemented in 3 different ways and isolated to 3 different packages, and I would like to reduce duplication of function prototypes in the specification of the parent package. I thought about interfaces and abstract functions but that forces me to still have duplicates. The only way I see doing this is having a record of function pointers, but is there not an OOP way to get around it?

Here is an example of what I want to avoid

```
package Parent_P is
  type Something is interface;
  function A(S : Something) return Boolean is abstract;
  function B(S : Something) return Boolean is abstract;
  function C(S : Something) return Boolean is abstract;
  package Child_1 is
    type Something_1 is new Something
    overriding function A(S : Something_1) return Boolean;
    overriding function B(S : Something_1) return Boolean;
    overriding function C(S : Something_1) return Boolean;
  end Child_1;
  package Child_2 is
    type Something_2 is new Something
    overriding function A(S : Something_2) return Boolean;
    overriding function B(S : Something_2) return Boolean;
    overriding function C(S : Something_2) return Boolean;
  end Child_2;
  package Child_3 is
    type Something_3 is new Something
    overriding function A(S : Something_3) return Boolean;
    overriding function B(S : Something_3) return Boolean;
    overriding function C(S : Something_3) return Boolean;
  end Child_3;
```

Ideally I could have something like this, but with OOP

```
package Parent_P is
  type Access_A is access function return Boolean;
  type Access_B is access function return Boolean;
  type Access_C is access function return Boolean;
  type Something is record
    A : Access_A := null;
    B : Access_B := null;
    C : Access_C := null;
  end record;
  package Child_1 is
    procedure Set_Pointers(S : in out Something);
  end Child_1;
  package Child_2 is
    procedure Set_Pointers(S : in out Something);
  end Child_2;
  package Child_3 is
    procedure Set_Pointers(S : in out Something);
  end Child_3;
```

Comment: Why do you want an "OOP way" to do this?  OOP is a tool.  You use it when you want the benefits of the tool.  It is not a magic pill where you use it in your program and your code just magically gets better.  I'm not saying that OOP is the wrong tool here; I'm just warning against wanting to make something OOP for no better reason than "it's supposed to make everything better".

Comment: Yes, I know. So I am right to assume that I am better without OOP - with my goal being reducing prototype declaration overhead? Do you have another suggestion for a non-oop way? As far as I know this is the only way to have interchangeable implementations of subprograms

Comment: There's no appreciable "overhead" involved with additional declarations.  (Declaring a tagged type may itself involve a small amount of memory and run-time overhead--memory because of additional info stored for each tagged type, besides subprogram pointers, and run-time if the name has to be registered for some of the `Ada.Tags` functions.)  But if by "overhead" you just mean the extra text in your source to declare the subprograms: if you use Ada, you need to accept that things will be a bit verbose.  Please don't damage your design trying to get around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a record of access-to-function components as in your second example, there's no particular reason that I can see to declare a tagged type.

The debate should be between your first and your second example.  The first example, which you say you want to avoid, really is the "OOP way" of doing it (you could declare `Something` to be an `abstract tagged null record` instead of an `interface`; it doesn't make that much difference).  One advantage of doing it the first way is that it ties together certain subprograms that belong together.  In effect, in a static language such as Ada, C++, or Java, an object in OOP contains a *constant* record of subprogram pointers; that's how dispatching/polymorphism works.  (This record is called the `vtable` in C++; it doesn't have an official name in Ada but the term "dispatch table" is sometimes used.)  When you declare a new type or class, the polymorphic subprograms are either overridden or inherited, and the compiler creates a record of subprogram pointers that point to the overriding or inherited code.  Since this is constant, the rest of the program can't modify one of the "record" components to point to a different subprogram, but that's usually a good thing, because it would cause problems if a record pointed to subprograms that didn't work together.  Which is the second advantage of defining a tagged type and doing it this way: the subprograms that work together can also manipulate state that belongs to the object (or tagged record), working together by using the record components to pass information from one to another.

However, if there will never be any state manipulated by the functions, and if they are independent of each other (so that it *could* make sense to create a record with one function pointer from one place and another function pointer from another place), then the record containing the function pointers is probably a better abstraction.

So I think that whether to do things the "OOP way" or define a record of access-to-functions depends on your situation.  If there will never be any state, and the functions will be independent of each other, the record is probably good enough.  Otherwise use a tagged type as in the first example.  I'm not sure what about the first example you want to avoid, anyway.  In either case, you'll need to define 9 (3x3) different subprograms that do different things.  If you use a tagged type, you will also have to have declarations for all of those subprograms.  But if the motivation for avoiding this is to avoid having to write those declarations, that really isn't a sufficient reason.

Comment: There is no state change so the record is indeed the best option it seems. I wish I could make abstract functions for a tagged type and declare a new tagged type that could extend it without having to explicitly prototype all overriding functions and instead just implement them in the body of the package.

Comment: I compile with `-gnaty` (default style checks) which complains if I don’t put in subprogram specs - even where the only logical place for them is just before the body! I just put up with it.